# Remote bash script and executing the make command

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a device installed remotely that has Internet access. As i cannot SSH directly to it, the device downloads updates from a .txt file located in a server. This .txt file is interpreted by the device as a sequence of `bash` instructions.

Now, i'm planning an update that requires re-compiling a C program in the device after downloading and overwritting some files. The content of the .txt file for this update looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -o /path-to-file/newfile.c http://myserver/newfile.c
sleep 10 #wait so it can download
cd /path-to-file
make
sleep 10 #wait to make
sudo /path-to-file/my-program #test if it worked
```

I previously tested this method and it worked as expected, but never tested `make`. A couple of questions:

- Should it work?
- Is the `sleep` after `make` necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to retrieve a source code file into another directory, change to that directory, compile the source code with `make` and then execute the resulting binary:

```
mkdir -p path-to-file/
curl -o path-to-file/newfile.c http://www.csit.parkland.edu/~cgraff1/src/hello_world.c
cd path-to-file/
make newfile
./newfile
```

The `cd` is really not an integral part of the process, but it seems as if the question specifically pertains to performing the work in a directory other than the present working directory.

Comment: there is no need of any sleep?

Comment: No there is not a need for `sleep` as each of these commands operates sequentially. Perhaps of more use might be `sync` which just makes sure all data is full written to disk. Though `sleep` is often used like you are suggesting to slow a script down and allow various tasks to complete properly or to prevent overloading the network or console with data. Modern versions of `sleep` support fractional arguments though such as "sleep .1" which is generally all that is needed to slow the script down. One finds this in the console reporting and disk detection code of the debian initramfs scripts.